# The proof of remainder theorem for polynomials: $f(\lambda)=0$ if and only if $x-\lambda$ divides $f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-explanation

[image]

From the paragraph starting with "Let us now suppose that $f(\lambda) = 0$" the author states that if $\deg(f) \leq 0 $ then $f=0$. But if $\deg(f) = 0$ then $f$ can be any constant, and not necessarily $0$, for instance $f = 1$, $\deg(f) = 0$ but $x-\lambda$ doesn't divide $1$. Where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: That constant function $f$ must vanish at $\lambda$.

Comment: @user1337 ah, thank you

Comment: More clearly: $ $ if $\,\deg(f) \le 0\,$ then $\,f\,$ is constant so $\,f = f(\lambda) = 0\ $